# eslint ignore project .eslintrc

Tags: vim, syntastic, eslint

I'm working on a project that has an `.eslintrc` file checked in to source control at the root of the project.

The problem is that it has custom dependencies and when I use a tool to run my linting (syntastic with Vim) it fails. The dependencies are custom and I wish to skip running them in my editor.

I want to use another .eslintrc file, rather than the one which is in the root of the project.

**How can I ignore `<projectroot>/.eslintrc` and instead use `/custom/path/.eslintrc`?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A glance at the [ESLint docs](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface.html) tells us that you want to pass the `--no-eslintrc` option to make it ignore the `.eslintrc` in the project root and `--config /custom/path/.eslintrc` to make it use that file instead.

The [Syntastic README](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/master/README.markdown#faqargs) says you can configure the arguments given to eslint like so:

```
let g:syntastic_javascript_eslint_args = "--no-eslintrc --config /custom/path/.eslintrc"
```